# Efficient way to format string

Tags: python, string, formatting

i am writing the following sql query:

```
"select someTableName.somefield, count(*) from someTableName WHERE someTableName.TimeStamp > %s and someTableName.EndTimeStamp < %s group by someTableName.ProviderUsername;", [from_date, to_data]
```

this query can be used on three tables, so i do not want to fix the table name so what i am doing is like this.

```
"select %s.somefield, count(*) from %s WHERE %s.TimeStamp > %s and %s.EndTimeStamp < %s group by %s.ProviderUsername;", [tableName, tableName, tableName, from_date, tableName, to_data, tableName]
```

as you could see in above query i have to use `tableName` multiple times so i need to provide `tableName` for each occurance, is there any best way to achieve this??

**Edited**

i do not have `python 2.6` to use `str.format` and for some reason can't move to latest versionof python , i am using `python version 2.5.2`, so what is the best solution in this environment?

Comment: Be very careful that the variables going in to that string aren't unsanitized user-submitted content; this has SQL injection written all over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use named variables in string formatting, like this:

```
"select %(tableName)s.somefield, count(*) from %(tableName)s WHERE %(tableName)s.TimeStamp > %(fromDate)s and %(tableName)s.EndTimeStamp < %(to_data)s group by %(tableName)s.ProviderUsername;" %{'tableName':tableName, 'fromDate':fromDate, 'to_data':to_data}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have at least Python 2.6, you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
s = "select {0}.somefield, count(*) from {0} WHERE {0}.TimeStamp > {1} and {0}.EndTimeStamp < {2} group by {0}.ProviderUsername;"
query = s.format(tableName, fromDate, toDate)
```

That way you can use the same variable multiple times in the string.

Also note that this [is more future-proof than the old `%` formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: thanks for response, i have edited my post please read again, i using old python version.

Comment: @AamirAdnan: well, you got the answer for that case thrice already... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute with a dictionary

```
mydict = {'table': whatever, 'startdate': yourstartdate, 'enddate': yourenddate}
sql = "select %(table)s.somefield, count(*) from %(table)s WHERE %(table)s.TimeStamp > %(startdate)s and %(table)s.EndTimeStamp < %(enddate)s group by %(table)s.ProviderUsername;" % mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template = "select %(tableName)s.somefield, count(*) from %(tableName)s WHERE %(tableName)s.TimeStamp > %(fromDate)s and %(tableName)s.EndTimeStamp < %(to_data)s group by %(tableName)s.ProviderUsername;"
query = template % locals()
```